how to create an user guide with tabs
I have these tabs:
Widget tabs() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: NotificationListener(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _leaseTabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              const OptionsScreen(),
              const BalancesScreen(),
              ResumeScreen(
                balance: Balance(
                  id: "",
                  title: "",
                  balance: 0,
                  fromDate: DateTime.now().toString(),
                  timesAYear: 1,
                ),
                global: true,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          controller: _leaseTabController,
          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 5.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          tabs: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: Tab(
                child: Icon(LineIcons.cog, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: Tab(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(LineIcons.list, color: Colors.white),
                    Container(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      key: navigationBalances,
                      translate('balances'),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              child: Tab(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(LineIcons.coins, color: Colors.white),
                    Container(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      translate('total'),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

looking like that:

My idea is to show to the user a step-by-step guide for the first time. For that, I'm using this package and it's working fine:
https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark
Right now, I'm highlighting an element on that page following the steps from the package:

but I was wondering how can I have it working when there are some tabs in the same page. So next element to highlight would be the green card, but this is loaded as a tab:
const BalancesScreen(),

Do I need to repeat the same configuration for each page? How can I connect all of them to show something from a tab after showing something for the main container?
I was thinking on a provider, but not sure if that's the options for this package or not.

It was as simple as passing the key to the second screen.
BalancesScreen(incomeCardKey: incomeCard)

